# I want to make a custom middleware in laravel but i have not idea how to supply token input

Tags: php, laravel-8

"I want to make a custom middleware in laravel but I have not idea how to supply token input.
Here I want to match token input with my secret key.

The code is:"

[This is snapshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVDSH.png)

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Edit your question, add the relevant part of your code here as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this middleware for API, you can pass secret key in header at every request and function `handle` in `EnsureTokenIsValid`  should look like this

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
        if ($request->header('secret_key') !== 'your-secret-key'){
            // logic here
        }
        return $next($request);
}
```

If you use it for normal http requests pass it in body or query params

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
        if ($request->get('secret_key') !== 'your-secret-key'){
            // logic here
        }
        return $next($request);
}
```

Hope help u and happy coding !